# Allow user to terraform plan and import, but not apply

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

Terraform apply should be reserved for the CD server and to approved pull-requests only. However

- Going through git push and then waiting on the job in to run in the background for every typo and mistake made when writing the definitions adds quite a bit of overhead to the already not exactly fast process.
- While moving can be done with the move statements, there is already quite a few resources created by hand in the portal that I want to coopt under terraform management, so running import is needed a lot.

So for sake of efficiency it would be nice if we could run `terraform plan` and `terraform import` locally, but still for comfort of the paranoid main administrator limit the damage that can be done without proper review.

Some things should probably work with subscription-wide `Reader`, but I know at least functionapp settings and contents of keyvaults (terraform is to take care of updating various access keys—it's important part of why going to terraform) can't be accessed with that, and I am not sure whether role assignments can (managed identities are to be used where practical).

What minimal set of roles should be granted to be able to import at least most things in Azure without asking anything too dangerous?

Comment: I am not sure that the cloud makes a difference via IAM between `terraform plan` and `apply`... The only thing I can think of is having two prod and non-prod environments, where the testing is being done on the non-prod one. I imagine this : two service accounts in charge of modifying the infrastructure respectively in `prod` and `dev` envs, your devs only being able to impersonate the `dev` service account.

Comment: @Imad, the cloud does not know anything about terraform plan and apply. It only knows about the operations that terraform (provider) executes via its API. And plan and import only read the state. So they should work with fewer permissions.

Comment: @Imad, two environments are not applicable since the test environment would not have the manually created resources that are to be imported. Well, it would be applicable if we were starting from scratch with terraform—create manually in dev, import to terraform, then create prod from the resulting manifests. But since I want to take over existing environment, I need the import to run against prod.

Comment: I hope I'm understanding well, but I don't think there is something that is apparented to a "bulk-import" from analyzing the cloud components that exist already. The only way would be to list all those resources (manually) and write a shell script to `terraform import`.

Comment: @Imad, there is, actually—[terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer)—, but importing them one by one is good enough. The problem is that doing the import over pipeline would add a lot of extra time, but the apply should be only allowed by the pipeline to ensure the logs of the pipeline do actually represent the current state.